# Unidentified lake creature in the Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire DVD game

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

The Lake Challenge game in Disc 2 of the *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* DVD features an unidentified lake creature- a blue humanoid with huge jaws that attacks the player. It is distinct from the other inhabitants of the Black Lake (namely the mermaids and Grindylows).

Does anyone know what this creature might be?

Comment: This thing? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK1QL.png

Comment: @Valorum That is the only thing in The Lake game which I saw which is not a mer-person or Grindylow

Comment: I don't have the disc, but based on a few stills I managed to isolate, the head/mouth looks like a shark.  While it shows up at the beginning of your clip, it reappears at 1:03 and there are clearly visible arms.  In the book Krum transfigures his torso into a shark, and I never saw your mystery creature's lower body, so that's a possibility

Comment: @Punintended At first I thought it might be Krum, but looking at the video, it does not look much like he did when he was partially transfigured.

Answer (score 43):

It would appear to be Viktor Krum.

[image: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Viktor Krum saves Hermione]

You can clearly see his arms the second time he comes into view as well as a very shark like face and back matching how he looks in the film.

[image: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, The Lake DVD game]

It's a bit hard to spot the legs but these are the two times he's on screen. You can sort of see them trailing behind but any still just looks like a blur really.

[image: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, The Lake DVD game, first appearance] [image: Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, The Lake DVD game, second appearance]